# Diagonalisation of sparse matrix with two diagonals

Tags: matrices

In the course of solving another mathematical problem, I have run into a situation where I want to compute arbitrarily large powers of the following matrix:

$$\mathbf{M} = \frac{1}{m} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & m-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & m-2 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & m-2 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & m-1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & m \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

As you can see, this matrix is quite sparse --- it has only two diagonals of non-zero values, which are both simple sequences of numbers.  I would like to find the spectral decomposition of this matrix in order to make it easier to compute large powers of the matrix.  (Any other decomposition that lets me easily compute large powers of the matrix is just as good.)

**My questions:** Has this matrix form been analysed anywhere in the mathematics literature?  Does it have a name?  Is there any simple form for the spectral decomposition of the matrix (or any other decomposition that makes it easy to compute large powers)?

Comment: It's a bidiagonal matrix. While there is no closed form for their regular potency, one can give a generating function for $M^n$. However, many assumptions allow calculating a potency in a closed form, e.g. as in the Jordan-blocks, or as in your case.

Answer (score 1):

So you can diagonalize it as follows.

$\frac{1}{m}(PDP)$

Normally it's $P^{-1}DP$, but $P=P^{-1}$ in this case.

We have $P=  \begin{bmatrix}
\binom{m-1}{0}(-1)^0 &\binom{m-1}{1}(-1)^1& \binom{m-1}{2}(-1)^2 & \cdots \binom{m-1}{m-1}(-1)^{m-1} \\
0 & \binom{m-2}{0}(-1)^1 &\binom{m-2}{1}(-1)^2& \cdots \binom{m-2}{m-2}(-1)^{m-1} &  & \cdots &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I only filled out the first rows... but the pattern holds.

And D would simply be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....m down the diagonal.

I pulled this straight off of Wolfram Alpha after experimenting with $m=5$ and $m=6$, which I thought was enough.

[image]

If you want to explore more without heavy calculations on your own, use wolframalpha.com as an easy to use tool.

To get this, I simply entered

"((1,5,0,0,0,0),(0,2,4,0,0,0),(0,0,3,3,0,0),(0,0,0,4,2,0),(0,0,0,0,5,1),(0,0,0,0,0,6))" and WolframAlpha did the diagonalization trace eigenvalues eigenvectors etc. immediately